# INNER JOIN Help and tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Im currently trying to make a table with information from two mysql tables "order" and "order_items" as they both share order id

order

[image: http://gyazo.com/b5761696c5650d0f24d883fd914f3564.png]

order_items

[image]

I want to display a table like this with the product names in the same row which would take a loop maybe

[image]

i want do this with an inner join as it more marks for what im doing

This is what i have at the moment but doesnt work at the moment

```
$query = "SELECT order.date_bought, order.total_price, order_items.product_name FROM order INNER JOIN order_items ON order.order_id = order_items.order_id WHERE order.student_id = $id ORDER BY order_id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i=0;

while($i < $num){
$date_bought = mysql_result($result,$i,"date_bought");

echo $date_bought;

}
```

error: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

but im pretty sure its because of the query

Comment: But your tables are all the same?!

Comment: please correct  order_items structure..

Comment: sorry the images were wrong

Comment: You can try using group_concat(). Only problem is mysql caps char limit to 1024 or so.

Comment: please put your question with proper attention, please correct order_items structure in question

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word, escape it:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id,
  o.date_bought, 
  o.total_price, 
  oi.product_name 
FROM `order` AS o
INNER JOIN order_items AS oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE o.student_id = $id 
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC;
```

Try to avoid these names.

---

If you want to display the products names in the same row for each order, use `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id,
  o.date_bought, 
  o.total_price, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(oi.product_name SEPARATOR ' ') AS ProdcutNames
FROM `order` AS o
INNER JOIN order_items AS oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id 
WHERE o.student_id = $id 
GROUP BY o.order_id,
         o.date_bought, 
         o.total_price
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC;
```

Comment: It still throws the error.
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given


maybe my php is wrong? or how can i test if something is being retrieved

Comment: @user2146226 Please try to get the SQL error. You can test it directly in MySQL, or the phpadmin.

Comment: DONE IT. i had to concatanate the $id, THANK YOU.

atm it displays the same date a billion times so my loop is wrong etc, ill try to figure out how i display this into a table otherwise ill ask a new question later. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I see you a beginner in mysql. Try it:

```
SELECT * FROM order o INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id WHERE order.student_id = $id GROUP BY o.order_id ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

The "group" is not to duplicate the results.